# Missing gem for Metasploit

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to install metasploit on my raspberry pi 3 B. But I have a gem that keeps failing. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
root@raspberrypi:/opt/metasploit-framework# gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.1'
```

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1/ext/nokogiri
```

/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20171225-5790-o99pl4.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/nokogiri-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/extensions/arm-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.8.1/gem_make.out
root@raspberrypi:/opt/metasploit-framework#

So I'm not really sure what to do. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Alessio

Answer (score 2):

## First:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev
```

## Second:

```
sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.8.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'
```

Had the same problem with 1.8.2 on raspbian stretch.